# Hardhat + Waffle + Hardhat: Nonce has already been used

Tags: ethers.js, testing, hardhat, nonce, waffle

This week at a talking by our friend [Patrick Collins](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11969592/patrick-collins) during the Chainlink Spring 2022 Hackathon schedule, I took knowledge of the possibility of moving ahead of time on the blockchain during tests:

```
  async moveTime(amount: number) {
    console.log("Moving blocks...");
    await network.provider.send("evm_increaseTime", [amount]);

    console.log(`Moved forward in time ${amount} seconds`);
  }
```

So I'm trying to use it on my tests but, from the moment I started to use it, my tests started to have this exception:

```
Error: nonce has already been used [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-NONCE_EXPIRED ] (error={"name":"InvalidInputError","code":-32000,"_isProviderError":true}, method="sendTransaction", transaction="0x02f872827a69148459682f008461277a0a8401bad45894532323de74bab864b7005d910e5bd8562d038b9b8084478c7d5fc001a0e987896b237af1c098617321e8356a5dd903b834f7fe9e4188f6b5858530d263a06fce96280dc21b5d41909353ae33897f4155a3742d1deefac0f77575d9ec9151", code=NONCE_EXPIRED, version=providers/5.6.1)
```

I've found out a similar post with this kind of error at [NONCE_EXPIRED error with ethers.js on local hardhat node](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/121651/nonce-expired-error-with-ethers-js-on-local-hardhat-node) and have followed the instructions about doing the snapshot but it didn't solve the problem:

```
before(async function () {
    const accounts = waffle.provider.getWallets();

    ....
    this.loadFixture = waffle.createFixtureLoader(accounts);

    snapshot = await waffle.provider.send("evm_snapshot", []);
  });

  after(async function () {
    await waffle.provider.send("evm_revert", [snapshot]);
  });
```

Anyone else faced this kind of problem and succeded solving it?

**IMPORTANT:** The error does not happen in all execution, only when I run the tests few seconds after a previous execution.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

I've found out the cause of problem I reported above. In my case specifically, the problem was not related to the JSON-RPC methods `evm_increaseTime` and the solution was not snapshoting the blockchain.

The problem is that in some of my tests when asserting for events emitted and reverted conditions I've done it in a wrong way.

On the contrary of regular assertions, where we pass the value being asserted to `expect` function:

```
expect(BigNumber.from(100)).to.be.within(BigNumber.from(99), BigNumber.from(101));
```

And, of course, if it's remote call we make use of `await` in order to not pass a Promise but the actual value returned:

```
expect(await token.balanceOf(wallet.address)).to.equal(993);
```

To assert emitted events and revertions, we can** pass the Promise to `expect` and we have to use await for the `expect` function:

```
await expect(token.transfer(walletTo.address, 7))
  .to.emit(token, 'Transfer')
  .withArgs(wallet.address, walletTo.address, 7);


await expect(token.transfer(walletTo.address, 1007))
  .to.be.revertedWith('Insufficient funds');
```

There is even a note in the Waffle documentation about this:

> You must await the expect in order for the matcher to execute
> properly. Failing to await will cause the assertion to pass whether or
> not the event is actually emitted!

After going throughout all my testing code and repairing all occurrences of this mistake, it is working just fine.

** My tests work well when I pass the Promise returned by contract's function calling to `expect`function, as well as when I make use of await before the function calling and pass the receipt itself in spite of the Promise.